# Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object?

Tags: c#, exception

I am programming in C#; the code was working about a week ago, however it throws an exception and I don't understand at all what could be wrong with it.

```
Var root = new CalculationNode(); -> Throw exception.
```

In the call stack thats the only thing listed, I've been told that it could be that I need a clean build, but I am open to any ideas or suggestions.

Thanks,
-Bill

Update:
Exception's Detail

System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code
  Message=Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
  Source=Calculator.Logic
  StackTrace:
       at ~.Calculator.Logic.MyBaseExpressionParser.Parse(String expression) in ~\Source\Calculator.Logic\MyBaseExpressionParser.cs:line 44
       at ~.Calculator.Logic.Tests.MyBaseCalculatorServiceTests.BasicMathDivision() in ~\Projects\Tests\Calculator.Logic.Tests\MyBaseCalculatorServiceTests.cs:line 60
  InnerException:

CalculationNode's code:

```
public sealed calss CalculationNode
{
 public CalculationNode()
{
this.Left = null;
this.Right = null;
this.Element = new CalculationElement();
}

public CalculationNode Left {get;set;}

public CalculationNode Right {get;set;}

public CalculationElement Element {get; set;}
}
```

CalculationElement's code:

```
public sealed class CalculationElement
{
 public CalculationElement()
{
Value = string.Empty;
IsOperator = false;
}

public string Value {get; set}

public bool IsOperator {get; set}
}
```

Comment: What's `CalculationNode`?  What's the exception's stack trace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Calculator.Logic.MyBaseExpressionParser.Parse` method is throwing an exception at line 44.

You should look at the method and figure out what the problem is.

Comment: Thanks, I see what was wrong it turned out was a simple logic error with my validation method.

Answer (score 1):

First place to look would be in the constructor code of `CalculationNode`. You could set a breakpoint in that constructor and step through the code and see what problem is occurring.

If you are doing any type of logging, using a tool like [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/), you should check any logs you may have.

And as already mentioned, it's always a good idea to look at the stack trace to see if that sheds any light.

Answer (score 0):

If you recently updated a service pack, You may need to update a database Schema.

Comment: There is no database involved here.

Comment: then pay no mind to that solution :D

Answer (score 0):

It looks like either `Calculator.Logic.MyBaseExpressionParser.Parse`, which is throwing the exception, is called somewhere else in your code, and it only *looks* like that line is causing the exception. Perhaps you're debugging into a version of the exe that is not the most current version of the code, or there's another thread executing `Parse`.